# Cannot pass C array as memoryview in Cython

Tags: python, arrays, cython

Here is the example pyx file

```
# yy.pyx
def foo(double[::1] args):
    cdef double[3] v = [args[0], args[1], 0]
    bar(v)

def bar(double[::1] args):
    pass
```

and the main (I run in ipython for simplicity)

```
import numpy as np
import pyximport

pyximport.install()

import yy

yy.foo(np.arange(2.0))
```

Then I got the error

```
In [3]: run main.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/src/cython-numpy/main.py:8
      4 pyximport.install()
      6 import yy
----> 8 yy.foo(np.arange(2.0))

File ~/src/cython-numpy/yy.pyx:3, in yy.foo()
      1 def foo(double[::1] args):
      2     cdef double[3] v = [args[0], args[1], 0]
----> 3     bar(v)
      4
      5 def bar(double[::1] args):

File ~/src/cython-numpy/yy.pyx:5, in yy.bar()
      3     bar(v)
      4
----> 5 def bar(double[::1] args):
      6     pass
      7

File stringsource:660, in View.MemoryView.memoryview_cwrapper()

File stringsource:350, in View.MemoryView.memoryview.__cinit__()

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

If I use `array.array` for `v`, then there is no error. But I don't know why C array cannot be used here

Answer (score 0):

The error goes away with this definition

```
cpdef bar(double[::1] args):
    pass
```

or `cdef`

Comment: Yes - that matters sense. A `def` function is just a Python callable with address to a memoryview inside it. So you'd need to convert the C array to a Python object, call the function, and then get a memoryview of the converted object. `cdef` and `cpdef` you call directly